# How do I read a string as a date into python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, datetime

I have a csv file that I am reading into pandas. The file has a field called Period with values : 31DEC2017,31JAN2018 etc. Pandas reads it as a string, but I need to read it as a date. How do I do it?
I tried:

```
pd.read_csv("test.csv" ,dtype={'PERIOD':time})
```

But it does not work. I even tried :

```
dtype={'PERIOD':date})
dtype={'PERIOD':datetime})
```

Still gives me error

Comment: `parse_dates ` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: The answer in the linked question is an absolute mess, but I'd recommend reading as string and using `pd.to_datetime` once it's in memory. Otherwise, `parse_dates=['PERIOD']`